# remove line or shadow above tabbar

Tags: flutter, dart

im working on a UI app. manage to implement tabbar but got quite confused about a thin line above the tabbar. it's either a line or shadow, not sure. already run several code but doesn't manage to remove the line. the weird thing is, It seems to work the way i wanted on mobile ( chrome - mobile version / tablet ) but the line pop when opened in web version.

here is the problem ( that single line above the blue tabbar )
[image]

here is it, the same code when opened in mobile mode.

[image]

perfect clear without the line.

i try 2 version of code

```html
 DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
          
          child: new Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: new SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(child: new Container()),
                  new TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.white,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey[700],
                    indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
```

```html
DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
            child: _tabBar,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
```

both of them works, but results are the same. that thin line above the tab bar persist. i just want to remove it. can anyone help ?
fullcode : github.com/CrazyBunnyz/Sociominer_V2/tree/error

Comment: You want to remove white line of tabbar?

Comment: the top 1, based on my 2 sc there is a small gap of line between the header and tabbar. i don't understand whether that is a line or shadow but I just want to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. lol. the problem lies in the header. instead of using container as the header, I just need to put the header ( container ) inside appbar first. i find it quite weird cause I don't put any decoration or style in the header. it has been solved anyway so no complain. thank you for everyone who  takes their time to help me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

change `indicatorColor` to transparent.

you have set indicator color to white.

replace that with `indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,`

It will work.

[image: This is Tab 1.]

[image: This is Tab 2.]

Comment: no it doesnt works, the problem still persist. do note that it looks normal on mobile version of chrome, just like your sc. it only came out on the web version based on the chrome

Comment: Are you applying 'navigationBarTheme' data in MaterialApp?

Comment: I solved my own question. lol. the problem lies in the header. instead of using container as the header, I just need to put the header ( container ) inside appbar first. i find it quite weird cause I don't put any decoration or style in the header. it has been solved anyway so no complain. thank you for your time to help me solve my problem